# How to restart Heroku worker using heroku gem

Tags: heroku

I'm struggling to find how to call the equivalent of (taken from [this article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ps#process_restarts)):

```
heroku restart worker.1
```

using the [`heroku` gem](https://github.com/heroku/heroku). I see there are `restart` and `ps_restart` methods but don't see where I can specify to only restart this 1 worker and not the whole app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm doing specific worker restarts from within the app using a cron. Like this:

```
heroku = Heroku::Client.new(ENV['APP_USERNAME'], ENV['APP_PASSWORD'])
heroku.ps_restart(ENV['APP_NAME'], :ps =>'worker.1')
```

From the [Heroku API Doc](https://api-docs.heroku.com/ps)

Answer (score 57):

Here is the command to restart any particular process

```
heroku ps:restart worker.1 --app APP_NAME
```

Comment: Since we already know from the question that the particular process is `worker.1`, we could reword it to say `heroku ps:restart worker.1 --app APP_NAME`.

Answer (score 5):

Use the "heroku-api" gem, NOT the "heroku" gem. Using the "heroku" gem this way still works (as of today), but is deprecated. It's meant to be used via the console.

https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb

The api gem looks very easy to use. Grab you API key from the heroku website, put it in your app config variables, and call:

```
require 'heroku-api'
heroku.post_ps_restart('app', 'ps' => 'web.1')   # restart 'web.1' process for 'app' app
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you have to take the "[platform-api](https://github.com/heroku/platform-api)" gem ([documentation here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/platform-api/1.0.0/toplevel)) from heroku because the "heroku" gem is not working anymore and the "heroku-api" gem is used to interact with the Heroku Legacy API. The Legacy API will be sunset on April 15th, 2017.

First you have to create an oAuth token via the heroku toolbelt command line tool:

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-oauth
$ heroku authorizations:create -d "Platform API example token"
Created OAuth authorization.
  ID:          2f01aac0-e9d3-4773-af4e-3e510aa006ca
  Description: Platform API example token
  Scope:       global
  Token:       e7dd6ad7-3c6a-411e-a2be-c9fe52ac7ed2
```

Use the Token value when instantiating a client:

```
require 'platform-api'
heroku = PlatformAPI.connect_oauth('e7dd6ad7-3c6a-411e-a2be-c9fe52ac7ed2')
```

restart a specific dyno with this command:

```
heroku.dyno.restart(app_id_or_app_name, dyno_id_or_dyno_name)
```

or restart all with this command:

```
heroku.dyno.restart_all(app_id_or_app_name)
```

You can get the ids of all your apps with

```
heroku.app.list
```

And the ids of the app's dynos via

```
heroku.dyno.list(app_id_or_app_name)
```

Comment: Is the old method of using the HEROKU_API_KEY config var now redundant? Should I save the OAuth token as a new config var?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on coderuby's answer a bit:

```
heroku = PlatformAPI.connect_oauth(ENV['PLATFORM_API_TOKEN'])

worker_ids = heroku.dyno
  .list(ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME'])
  .select { |dyno| dyno['type'] == 'worker' }
  .map { |dyno| dyno['id'] }

worker_ids.each do |id|
  heroku.dyno.restart(ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME'], id)
end
```

Having set the appropriate environment variables. You could include this in a rake task then have Heroku's scheduler run it when you see fit.